# Git branch is still on same line as master

Tags: git, branch, git-flow, feature-branch, branching-strategy

I am getting something unexpected happening in the git tree. I have created a branch off of master, however while I am performing commits on the new branch it appears as though these are taking place in the same code line as master...

[image]

[image]

As you can see, on the very left hand side is the code line for master (dark blue) and right at the top we can see Sprint_15 which is a branch taken from master that appears to have commits on the same line... I am not sure why this is taking place. I would expect to see the code diverge into a new line since features are being merged into Sprint_15 and not master...

My thought is that by merging Sprint_14 and Sprint_15 together this has done something funky to the history but I am not sure why.

I am still fairly new to git so some of its underpinnings still confuse me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems that you are a bit mistaken on how git works (which is normal because you said you are new to git)

Each branch does not necessarily get it's own line. If your branch `Sprint_15` has it's base as `master` and `Sprint_15` is any number of commits ahead of `master` then they will share the same line. As soon as `master` gets a new commit then I think you will see what you expect.

You can test this in a separate git repo like this.

```
$ mkdir testing && cd testing
$ git init  # should put you on master branch by default
$ touch testFile.txt
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
$ git branch newBranch
$ git checkout newBranch # switch from master to newBranch

### modify the testFile.txt in some way and then...
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "first commit on newBranch"
```

Now if you use the same tool to look at your repo, you should see only a single line, like this:
[image: same line]

Now go back to the master branch and make another commit:

```
$ git checkout master
### make another change to testFile.txt
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "second commit on master"
```

Now you will see each branch having it's own line like you were expecting, like this:[image]

Comment: this seems like the correct answer, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I'm curious, is there any way to force Git (or GUI tool) to display the new-branch (instead of master) as a straight line? Because sometimes I want to see entire tree but keep a specific branch as my "line of interest" around which everything else should be split off.

Comment: @JustAMartin I think it will depend on the GUI tool you use. In SourceTree instead of displaying `All Branches` you can select `Current Branch`. GitKraken has something similar which they call `Solo`ing a branch. Maybe this will be close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is a speculation, but I suggest that the reason your current feature branch appears to be on the same line as `master` is because currently that branch is directly ahead of `master` by some number of commits.  To test this, try doing a pull on the latest `master` branch.  If this changes your configuration such that `Sprint_15` appears as a separate line, then my hunch was correct.

In any case, you can always check such things directly from the Git bash if you are in doubt.